# The Origins of a Confusing Maze

Tags: geometry, mazes

Behold a maze of fuses (the black dotted lines) laid out on a grid:

[image: a confused maze]

The fuses can be lit, causing sparks to burn along them at a perfectly uniform rate: one segment per second. Your goal is to light the fuses in exactly four (4) places so that all sparks extinguish at *exactly the same time*.

The rules:

1. fuses may only be lit on the corners of grid squares (that is, the "gaps" between the fuse segments); all fuses must be lit at the same time
2. if $n$ spark(s) meet at an $n$-way intersection, they extinguish; this includes the case of a single spark reaching a dead-end
3. if $n$ spark(s) meet at a $k$-way intersection, with $k > n$, they do not extinguish; instead, they split or merge if necessary and continue to follow all outgoing branches (all branches that sparks didn't come in on)

**Can you figure out which four places to light the fuses?**

---

**Hint:** See https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu4qO.png

The four colours (red, purple, blue, and green) correspond to fuses burned by sparks spreading from the first, second, third, and fourth spark origins, respectively.

---

### Example

As an example, consider one part of the grid:

[image: a smaller grid]

Lighting the fuse at D5 is a potential solution. It will start burning north and south, reaching B3 in 4s and B6 at 3s, splitting at both. The B3 north spark and B6 south spark will continue burning (exiting the grid). The B3 south and B6 north sparks will reach B4 at exactly the same time (5s) and merge, continuing to burn along the western branch.

Lighting the fuse at D4 is *not* a potential solution. We see that in this case, two sparks will meet and extinguish at B5 after 5s, but other sparks (at A2 and A4, and possibly B7) will still be burning, meaning all sparks do not extinguish at the same time.

Comment: I'm a little confused by how the extinguishing happens. What would happen next for [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-qG0FowKmvXI_CxJcmgSdrnTnVqn4Jj_A_GlWrJ3Eno=w577-h579-no)? The green circle represents the 4 places that were lit.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Thanks. I've made the fix.

Comment: @Allan: The four fuses meeting at the four way intersection would extinguish per rule 2. The four fuses not at the intersection would all still be burning at this point, violating the "all fuses must extinguish at the same time" requirement and disqualifying this as a solution.

Comment: @COTO Ok, I see now. So the correct solution to this puzzle would have every part of the maze burning at the very end right?

Comment: Nice puzzle. If I'm not mistaken, just looking at that small part of the grid only D3, D5 and D6 are potential starting points (or end points I guess) and I believe this should also be the case for the entire puzzle then

Comment: @IvoBeckers: Your first observation is correct. Your second one isn't. (There are definitely ignition points and end points that appear outside this block.)

Comment: Spend quite some time on this lol. Are you sure there is a solution?

Comment: Your example is not complete, since you are presenting part of puzzle. What happens with B6 down (south) when you start with D5? You also use fuse interchangeably - a single edge and "fuse path" - at B4 the path is continues because merger is regarded as "fuse path continuation". Right?

Comment: @IvoBeckers: Unless I've erred in my solution (which I double- and triple-checked), there is a solution. I'll post a hint shortly.

Comment: @Moti: You're right. I'll update the question to make the distinction clearer.

Comment: Do you need to light all the fuses at once? Also, *can* you light them all at once, or is there a delay between lighting them?

Comment: @mdc32: Good question. Yes, you must light them all at once. I'll stipulate this in the problem statement. I've also added a hint.

Comment: @IvoBeckers: Sunuva... I checked again, and wouldn't you know everything is perfect except *one* darned branch that's two units too short. Darn it anyway. Very sorry. I've updated the main figure and the hint.

Comment: By the way, I really like this kind of puzzle. Did you make it yourself? You know where I could find similar puzzles? If not, it would be great if you posted more of these kind of puzzles here

Comment: @IvoBeckers: I came up with the concept and this puzzle. It may well have been done before, but I don't know where or by whom. I'll put up a slightly different take on the genre later this week. I think this one was a bit too difficult for most.

Comment: I know it's solved already, but it was fun... I built an interactive animation for this: [check it out](http://codepen.io/jnfsmile/full/eNeJLB)

Comment: @JNF: Very cool. :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the below picture is your intended solution where red dots are where the fuses are lit and black where they die out. however, the error is on the pink dot because at that point 2 sparks need to merge but they arive there on different times. Nice puzzle though! Kept me quite busy :)

> [image]

Comment: That's excellent. It's the correct solution. The error is a "transcription error" of sorts from the model I published vs. the model I used for validation. I'll award you 50 rep when the option becomes available for not only solving the puzzle, but fixing it as well. Great work. ;)

Comment: I've amended the puzzle and the hint to remedy the error.

Comment: +1 great job. What technic did you use to solve that?

Comment: Well. At first I used the fact that the dead ends should always be start or end points. Trying them first as starting points I found out quickly that the top two ones at least couldn't be starting points

Comment: So I then worked backwards from those points and found the starting point at the top quickly. Now knowing that the fuses last 12 seconds it's a matter of trying different routes and working backwards from known end points

Comment: @IvoBeckers, how is [this](http://codepen.io/jnfsmile/full/eNeJLB) for a test ground?